# How to SELECT with IF clause in mysql over query

Tags: mysql

I want to select columns `id_thread`, `no_tlp`, and `nama` (contact name)

But not all number are save on `tb_contact` (eg: sms addres from sms-gateway, they have auto name value)

So IF nama = NULL THEN SET the 'nama'='no_tlp'

```
SELECT 
    id_thread, no_tlp, 
    IF(tb_contact.`nama` = 'NULL' THEN SET nama = no_tlp) AS nama  
FROM
    tb_sms
LEFT JOIN 
    tb_contact ON  tb_sms.`no_tlp` = tb_contact.`no_tlp` 
GROUP BY 
    id_thread ASC
```

That's my query but it didn't work,

Somebody help me please

Comment: you must use 2 sql queries, one for select the field that you want to compare, then save true or false in a boolean var, close that connection and finaly if this var is true or false do something with the second query (an update in this case). (i mean you have to use 2 in your logic language, php for example)

Comment: do you need the corrected value to be stored, or do you just need the correct output from your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT id_thread, tb_contact.`no_tlp`, IF(tb_contact.`nama` IS NULL, tb_contact.`no_tlp`, tb_contact.`nama`) AS nama  
FROM tb_sms
LEFT JOIN tb_contact 
ON  tb_sms.`no_tlp` = tb_contact.`no_tlp` 
GROUP BY id_thread ASC
```

Or use `COALESCE` like:

```
SELECT id_thread, tb_contact.`no_tlp`, COALESCE(tb_contact.`nama`, tb_contact.`no_tlp`) AS nama  
FROM tb_sms
LEFT JOIN tb_contact 
ON  tb_sms.`no_tlp` = tb_contact.`no_tlp` 
GROUP BY id_thread ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sql queries.

```
SELECT id_thread, no_tlp, CASE  WHEN tb_contact.`nama` = 'NULL'  THEN no_tlp END AS nama  
FROM tb_sms
LEFT JOIN tb_contact 
ON  tb_sms.`no_tlp` = tb_contact.`no_tlp` 
GROUP BY id_thread ASC
```